# enable popup documentation in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide

I have simple problem!
Is there any option in this ide like auto popup documentation window in netbeans or quick documentation lookup in IntelliJ idea?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

Press `F2` when you are on a method, class name etc and Eclipse will display a pop-up containing documentation. You can also hover over them with your mouse to get the same information.